# How to pass a win32 error in C# to Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, error-handling

I have a PowerShell script that creates a new type using C# code that I borrowed from somewhere else.  I've discovered that although I can capture PowerShell errors, I don't get anything back when the error comes from the function call to the DLL that the type references.

The C# code (that I copied) has a Try/Catch statement like this:

```
try {
   int retVal = AddFontResource(fontFilePath);
   bool posted = PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM.FONTCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
   return retVal;
}
catch { return 0; }
```

calling a function of 'gdi32.dll'.  In PowerShell I have a Try/Catch where I include:

```
Catch { Write-Warning "$($error[0].ToString())" }
```

If the failure is on the `AddFontResource(fontFilePath)` call, PowerShell "catches" that there was an error (although I'm not sure how), but `$error` is null and the "catch" creates it's own error.

How can I capture the error coming from the DLL function and pass it through to PowerShell to at least give me some additional information upon failure?

Doing some research, I **think** this will work as a replacement `catch` statement in the C# code, but I don't know how to create the failure to test it.

```
catch { throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()); }
```

Can anyone confirm and/or improve my understanding?

Thanks!

Comment: From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourcea): "If the function fails, the return value is zero. No extended error information is available.". I would add a check in the C# code like `if(retVal == 0){ throw new Exception("Adding fonts failed");}` and then consume that exception in PowerShell

Comment: it is either returned as standard error or standard output.  See : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout

Comment: @jdweng Not true. The other comment is accurate.